# Filter apply in multidimensional array object with child node of response in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter

I have result of array object and need to apply in filter with `response_id`. This key is exist in child of response. If I search with 23764, 23765 I want all Question objects that has AT LEAST 2 RESPONSES, with the id 23764 and 23765, and these are the only two response objects that I want in the response array.

If I search with only 23764 I want all Question objects that has response object with that id, and only that response object in the array.

My current implementation attempts to do something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    
    $scope.data = [
    {
        "id": "1341",
        "question": "What about this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Every thing "
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23765",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1342",
        "question": "What dislike about this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Nothing"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23765",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1343",
        "question": "What suggestion(s) this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Nothing "
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23765",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
        ]
    }
  ];
  
  var res = ($filter('filter')($scope.data, {response:{response_id:'23764,23765'}}, true));
  console.log(res);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

**Desired Result**

```
[
{
    "id": "1341",
    "question": "What about this chaneel?",
    "response": [
        {
            "response_id": "23764",
            "comment": "Every thing "
        },
        {
            "response_id": "23765",
            "comment": "No"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1342",
    "question": "What dislike about this chaneel?",
    "response": [
        {
            "response_id": "23764",
            "comment": "Nothing"
        },
        {
            "response_id": "23765",
            "comment": "No"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1343",
    "question": "What suggestion(s) this chaneel?",
    "response": [
        {
            "response_id": "23764",
            "comment": "Nothing "
        },
        {
            "response_id": "23765",
            "comment": "No"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are after? You use `23764,23765` as filter value. Do you want `or` or `and` logic for example?

Comment: @tasseKATT require with `and`

Comment: @tasseKATT I have comma separated value which has passed from view and need to apply in filter with `and` not `or`

Comment: I assume you don't want every object that has `response_id` = `23764` and `23765`, since there are none. You want each large object that has response objects with the matching ids, so at least two response objects? Sounds like a very specific filter.

Comment: @tasseKATT Yes you are right need specific filter which match ids in object and filter accordingly.

Comment: @tasseKATT is there any solution you have kindly share with me

Comment: To make it clear. You filter with `23764, 23765`. There is an object that only has one object in its response array: `{
            "response_id": "23764",
            "comment": "Every thing "
        }` Do you want this to be in the result or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113732/discussion-between-tassekatt-and-query-master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you filter with `23764,23765` and you want an array of all questions that contain one response object with id `23764` **AND** one response object with id `23765`, and these should be the only response objects inside the returned results nested response array.

There are plenty of ways to write a custom filter function for this.

Here is one example:

```
var myFilter = function(collection, values) {

  values = values.replace(' ', '').split(',');

  var result = [];

  collection.forEach(function(question) {

    var questionMatches = [];

    question.response.forEach(function(r) {

      if (values.indexOf(r.response_id) > -1) questionMatches.push(r);
    });

    if (questionMatches.length !== values.length) return;

    var questionCopy = angular.extend({}, question);

    questionCopy.response = questionMatches;

    result.push(questionCopy);
  });

  return result;
};

var filterValues = '23764, 23765';

var result = myFilter($scope.data, filterValues);
```

You probably want to add some argument checks and it can probably be optimized, but it should get you started at least.

Might also need to change the logic based on if you want copies of the original data or references.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/r6a5qbw4JJ6Zc5eFopLT?p=preview

Comment: Yup you are right there some change required in logic for the original data. second time this will filter in filtered data

Comment: Not if you pass the original data each time you want to filter, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I handle it ... now it perfectly fulfilled my requirement.. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular forEach loop for remove object.try this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    
    $scope.data = [
    {
        "id": "1341",
        "question": "What about this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Every thing "
            },
            {
                "response_id": "237657",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1342",
        "question": "What dislike about this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Nothing"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23765",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1343",
        "question": "What suggestion(s) this chaneel?",
        "response": [
            {
                "response_id": "23764",
                "comment": "Nothing "
            },
            {
                "response_id": "237654",
                "comment": "No"
            },
            {
                "response_id": "23766",
                "comment": ".."
            }
        ]
    }
  ];
   $scope.result = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data,function(d){
      angular.forEach(d.response,function(res,index){
          if(res.response_id == "23766"){
            d.response.splice(index,1);
             console.log(d.response);
            }
        })
    })
//console.log($scope.data);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre>{{data| json}}</pre>
  </div>
```

Comment: how we avoid 23766 response id after filter

Comment: what do you want exactly??

Comment: i have edit my question kindly see my desired result

Comment: I don't use static approach because i have dynamic result of array object